# Add MySQL result into PHP array

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to add results into array and print on screen.
Here's my code and nothing is printing...could someone help me take a look.

```
include('config.php');

$con = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
if (!$con){
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db('members', $con) or die(mysql_error()) ;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM people where status like '%married%' "; 
$result = mysql_query($sql);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $result_array[] = $row['id']; // <-------**here**             
}

return $result_array;       

echo($result_array);
mysql_close($con);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, change:

```
mysql_select_db(mtar, $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

To:

```
mysql_select_db('mtar', $con) or die(mysql_error());
```

Then remove `return $result_array;` - you don't need it and when used outside of a function it just halts execution of the script.

Finally, change

```
echo($result_array);
```

to:

```
print_r($result_array);
```

EDIT:  Some additional thoughts:

You don't need parentheses around the argument to `echo` - it's actually more efficient to leave them out:  `echo $var;` is quicker than `echo($var);`

If you're only ever going to use the `id` column, then don't select the whole row:  use `SELECT id FROM` instead of `SELECT * FROM`.

Are you sure you need the wildcards either side of "married"?  You may well do (depends on what the possible values of `status` are), but you probably don't.  So

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM people where status = 'married' ";
```

May be better,

Comment: Note: `print_r` should only be used for debugging purposes.

Comment: @daiscog - Thanks for that - it stopped me from cursing myself :)

Answer (score 5):

You're doing a `return` before you do the echo/mysql_close, so the echo/close calls never get executed. Unless you've got more code around this snippet, there's no point in having that return call, as you're not actually in a function, so the return is effectively acting as an "exit()" call, since you're already at the top of the execution stack.

Comment: Not to mention using `echo` on arrays won't give you much.